# "tuple index out of range" when converting python code to exe

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wrote a desktop program with Python. The module I am using is PyQT5. To convert the program to exe, I type the following into the console:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile index.py
```

And it gave an error:

```
293 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
293 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
305 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
305 INFO: wrote C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\Stok takip yazılımı\index.spec
307 INFO: UPX is not available.
309 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\emiry\\Desktop\\Stok takip yazılımı']
790 INFO: checking Analysis
790 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
791 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
794 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
804 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4341 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\emiry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
4343 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\emiry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
5301 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5441 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5454 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
5499 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\Stok takip yazılımı\index.py
5706 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook PyQt5.uic.port_v2 from 'C:\\Users\\emiry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-PyQt5.uic.port_v2.py'.
7020 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\emiry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
7021 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\emiry\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 782, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 714, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\Desktop\Stok takip yazılımı\index.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['index.py'],
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 439, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 265, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2061, in _safe_import_module
    n = self._scan_code(module, co, co_ast)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2645, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode(
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2749, in _scan_bytecode
    for inst in util.iterate_instructions(module_code_object):
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 147, in iterate_instructions
    yield from iterate_instructions(constant)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 139, in iterate_instructions
    yield from get_instructions(code_object)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 338, in _get_instructions_bytes
    argval, argrepr = _get_const_info(arg, constants)
  File "C:\Users\emiry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 292, in _get_const_info
    argval = const_list[const_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I'm using PyQT5 for the program's interface. What is the source of the problem? How can I solve it?

**All the modules I use are:** sys, PyQT5, datetime, sqlite3, tabulate, pandas, smtplib, email.mime.multipart.

Comment: The bug is in the `dis` module, used by pyinstaller. I'd start by making sure the installed version of `dis` explicitly supports Python 3.10.